# How to pass a json string from PHP to Python with quotes

Tags: python, php, arrays, json

I have passed a JSON string from PHP to Python but I am not able to use it in Python probably because all the quotes within the JSON string are erased when it comes in Python.

PHP code:

```
$post_json = json_encode($_POST);
echo shell_exec("python create_prescription.py $post_json");
return;
```

Python code:

```
import sys
import json

post_json = sys.argv[1]
print(post_json)
```

The output that I am expecting from Python is:

```
{"x":"Hello","y":"World"}
```

Instead what I am getting is:

```
{x:Hello,y:World}
```

Without the quotes, I am not able to parse the input in Python. Please tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Did you check what `$post_json` looks like within the PHP?

Comment: Yes, I did. Within PHP the JSON string is with quotes. but when I import it into Python, they disappear.

Comment: Hello there! I have found a solution apparently. You can check the posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Just encode the JSON in PHP and export the same in Python. Import the module base64 in Python and decode the string there.

PHP code:

```
$post_json = json_encode($_POST);
$post_json = base64_encode($post_json);

$command = "python create_prescription.py $post_json";
echo shell_exec($command);
return;
```

Python code:

```
import base64

post_json = sys.argv[1]
final_output = json.loads(base64.b64decode(post_json))
print(final_output)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

@Nitish Thorat ´s answer is great. However, if you want to work with the data in python you need to call again

```
#py
# ...
final_output = json.loads(base64.b64decode(post_json))
obj = json.loads(final_output)
```

I quess oftentimes you want to do something with the data back in php then, so

```
#py
print(json.dumps(obj))

//php
$tmp = exec("python create_prescription.py .$post_json");
$result = json_decode($tmp);
```

Just for the sake of completeness...